# Open existing activity with notification

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have an application that has a `MainActivity` and a `MessageInboxActivity`. If the user has the application backgrounded and they receive a message, I show a local notification. When the user taps on the notification, I want to resume the `MainActivity` that is currently running. However, in my testing, it's destroying the current `MainActivity`, showing the `MessageInboxActivity`, then hitting the back button will cause a new `MainActivity` to get created.

```
private void SendLocalNotification()
{
    var notificationID = 1;

    var title = "New Message";
    var message = Constants.Message.NewMessageNotificationText;
    var builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(Application.Context);
    builder.SetContentTitle(title);
    builder.SetContentText(message);
    builder.SetAutoCancel(true);
    builder.SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.pn_message_icon);

    var mainIntent = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));
    var finalIntent = new Intent(this, typeof(MessageInboxActivity));
    var stackBuilder = Android.Support.V4.App.TaskStackBuilder.Create(Application.Context);
    stackBuilder.AddNextIntent(mainIntent);
    stackBuilder.AddNextIntent(finalIntent);
    var resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.GetPendingIntent(0, (int)PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent);
    builder.SetContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

    var notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.From(Application.Context);
    notificationManager.Notify(notificationID, builder.Build());
}
```

The `MainActivity` is set as `LaunchMode=SingleTask`.

```
[Activity(Label = "MainActivity", Theme = "@style/MyTheme", 
          WindowSoftInputMode = SoftInput.AdjustPan, ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait, 
          LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleTask)]
public class MainActivity : BaseActivity
```

How can I make the existing `MainActivity` continue instead of being destroyed for a new one? I've done some searching and thought I was following the answers correctly, but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may refer to the document [activity](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html) and search for the attribute `android:launchMode`.

When you set the to `SingleTask` at the top of your `MainActivity` using `LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleTask`, your `MainActivity` is allowed to have only one instance in the system (a.k.a. Singleton). If there is an existed Activity instance in the system, the whole Task hold the instance would be moved to top while Intent would be delivered through `onNewIntent()` method.

For your scenario, you would set the `LaunchMode` to `LaunchMode.SingleTop`, for this mode, if there already is an Activity instance with the same type at the top of stack in the caller Task, there would not be any new Activity created, instead an Intent will be sent to an existed Activity instance through `onNewIntent()` method.